# Regex for matching the last two ".Something" occurrences of a string?

Tags: regex

I have input strings like these:

Example 1

```
Company.Product.Common.ExternalServices.Company.CompanyService.GetCompanyOptions(String id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Example 2

```
Company.Apis.Product.Api.Business.Logic.Employees.Manager.<HasAccess>d__15.MoveNext()
```

Example 3

```
Company.Caching.MemoryCache.MemoryLocalCacheProvider.GetMemoryCache()
```

---

I want to match the last two dot delimited sections. So, for the three examples above, I'd want to match this:

- CompanyService.GetCompanyOptions(String id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
- d__15.MoveNext()
- MemoryLocalCacheProvider.GetMemoryCache()

---

I've tried this regex so far: `[^.?]+$` But it only matches the last comma-delimited text, where I want the last two.

Comment: `[^.]+\.[^.(]+\([^)]+\)` would do it

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you, that does do it. Would it be possible to modify it so it's not reliant on the parenthesis though? I just want to get the last two items when delimiting by '.'

Comment: If your sample input and output are not your real problem then why did you use them? Supply additional examples of what data you expect to encounter.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That was a real input/output example, I just (incorrectly) assumed that the solution regex pattern would be agnostic to the contents between the periods. I've updated my question to reflect it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AndyLester I know my question didn't reflect it, but I had tried many things myself. I didn't bother putting down a code example because I figured that it would be a fairly simple problem for someone with more regex experience and an example wasn't needed, but I went ahead and updated my question with one.

Comment: You can make content inside of the parenthesis optional like so `[^.]+\.[^.(]+\([^)]*\)`

Answer (score 0):

In RegEx, a backslash `\` is used when you want to match a character that is normally considered special. In your case, `\.Something` (as you put it in the title) would work.

Comment: No it wouldn't as `\.Something` also mtaches all the prior such substrings

Comment: I didn't mean that `\.Something` was the complete solution, it was just an example. But thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

After trying more things, I found this pattern that seems to do what I need:

```
[^.?]+\.[^.?]+$
```